# Amending the Registry on another PC within the same domain

Tags: powershell

I'm a PowerShell noob, so go easy on me. This is what I've got so far. The rest of the script should be fine. I'm just having trouble connecting to another PC on the domain.

I've also started the RemoteRegistry process, so that shouldn't be an issue either (along with a wait command).

I literally just need to find a method to interact with another PC on the same domain. The cmdlets I've tried haven't been much use as of yet. I might just be using them incorrectly though. I basically just need to add a registry key to remote PCs, instead of logging on to their machine and doing it manually.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$computer ="xxxxxx"
Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computer
```

I have also tried:

```
$computer ="xxxxx"
Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer
```

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: I basically just need to add a registry key to remote PCs to delete the offline file cache. I don't want to do it manually all the time

Comment: I'm not familiar with the registry path for that, but I've posted a wmi way to do so (relies on RPC being available which is pretty normal)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wmi method to interact with a remote registry:

```
$PSCredential = Get-Credential
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter target computername'

$GwmiArgs = @{
    Class        = 'StdRegProv'
    Namespace    = 'Root\Default'
    List         = $True
    ComputerName = $ComputerName
    Credential   = $PSCredential
}
$Registry = Get-WmiObject @GwmiArgs
```

With this `$Registry` object, you have the following methods:
*(they all return a `[System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]` object)*

```
CheckAccess            ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [uint32] $Required)
CreateKey              ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName)
DeleteKey              ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName)
DeleteValue            ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
EnumKey                ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName)
EnumValues             ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName)
GetBinaryValue         ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
GetDWORDValue          ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
GetExpandedStringValue ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
GetMultiStringValue    ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
GetQWORDValue          ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
GetSecurityDescriptor  ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName)
GetStringValue         ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName)
SetBinaryValue         ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName, [byte[]] $Value)
SetDWORDValue          ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName, [uint32] $Value)
SetExpandedStringValue ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName, [string] $Value)
SetMultiStringValue    ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName, [string[]] $Value)
SetQWORDValue          ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName, [uint64] $Value)
SetSecurityDescriptor  ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [System.Management.ManagementObject#__SecurityDescriptor] $Descriptor)
SetStringValue         ([uint32] $DefKey, [string] $SubKeyName, [string] $PropertyName, [string] $Value)
```

And to add the remote registry key:

```
<#  Defined in WinReg.h:
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (2147483648)
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER (2147483649)
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (2147483650)
        HKEY_USERS (2147483651)
        HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG (2147483653)
#>
$HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 2147483650
$Registry.CreateKey($HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\path\to\offlinecachekey')
```

Comment: Could you walk me through the array? I'm not 100% sure  about the Root/Default in the namespace. Am I to change that to the reg path?

Comment: @RhaegoT That is called splatting.  It's a dictionary that contains the `key:value` for the arguments to `Get-WmiObject`.  You don't need to update any of that