# Trying to Retrieve A Reg Value From Remote Machines Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to retrieve a registry value from each computer using a for each loop and then output that value to a folder in a csv.
That part works fine. The part I am having an issue with is having powershell connect to the remote computers.

This is running internal only
I have admin rights across all workstations
Firewalls are configured to allow all traffic to pass

When I run this script I get this error for every workstation it tried to connect to:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server workstationX failed with
>   the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation.
>   Verify that the  specified computer name is valid, that the computer
>   is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the
>   WinRM service is enabled and  allows access from this computer. By
>   default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits
>   access to remote computers within the same local  subnet. For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At
>   C:\Users\Rich_Ellis\Desktop\O365\O365Channels\O365Channel.ps1:5 char:2
>   + {Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (workstationX:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

My script is:

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Users\Rich_Ellis\Desktop\O365\O365Channels\computers.txt"

    foreach ($Computer in $Computers)

{Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer 

$key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\CLickToRun\Configuration'
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name CDNBaseUrl).CDNBaseUrl | Export-CSV -path "\\s00itstorage\OfficeChannel\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)-O365Channel03292018.csv"}
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: See [`Get-Help about_Remote_Troubleshooting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6)

Comment: The error pretty much tells you what to check. Did you check those things?

Answer (score 0):

[Molding a previous answer to your use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388194/amending-the-registry-on-another-pc-within-the-same-domain/49388677#answer-49388677):

```
$HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 2147483650
$GwmiArgs = @{
    Class     = 'StdRegProv'
    Namespace = 'Root\Default'
    List      = $True
}

ForEach ($Computer in @(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Rich_Ellis\Desktop\O365\O365Channels\computers.txt'))
{
    $GwmiArgs['ComputerName'] = $Computer
    $Registry = Get-WmiObject @GwmiArgs
    $Registry.GetStringValue(
        $HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration',
        'CDNBaseUrl'
    ).sValue | Export-CSV -Path "\\s00itstorage\OfficeChannel\$Computer-O365Channel03292018.csv"
}
```

This uses wmi instead of psremoting to poll the information which may be easier to rely on as it is already configured/enabled on most PCs and can utilize IP addresses due to DCOM/RPC (psremoting only supports kerberos by default)

This solution can be further improved by using `Invoke-WmiMethod` instead of creating a wmi object for each poll, but I haven't done the work already for that!